# Automatically adding error bars to all data points

Tags: plotting

I have been adding error bars to data points like this:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{2, 2}, 
   ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{3, 4}, ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{4, 6}, 
   ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{5, 7}, ErrorBar[0.2]}, {{6, 10}, 
   ErrorBar[0.2]}}]
```

However, this is very tedious to do if you have a lot of data points. Is there a way to define a "Error bar function" which can be automatically applied to all points instead of typing everything manually? Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? The options available to you depend on the version. Is `Around` available to you?. In which format do you have your data and errors? Please [edit] your question to add all the relevant information.

Comment: `ErrorListPlot[{#, ErrorBar[0.2]} & /@ data]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}, {6, 10}};
clist = {#[[1]], Around[#[[2]], 0.2]} & /@ pts
```

[image]